# Load Data form one SQL table to Multiple Excel sheet in SQL 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

How to load Data form one SQL table to Multiple Excel sheet in SQL 2005 through SSIS

Answer (score 0):

Use BI studio to create a new project.

Create a new data flow task.

From the toolbox drag an OLE DB Source and an excel data flow destination you need.

Choose the OLE DB Source and drag the destination arrow to the excel destination.

Click each datasource and configure the details.

In the control flow you can copy the flow as many times you need and change to excel file destination to another file.

Comment: I am having one SQl table with year wise data. iwant to export data in to different different excel yearwise using SSIS.

Comment: Have you worked with reporting services? You can make report grouped by year(this will make a sheet per year in excel), and have a subscription rendered to excel to deliver the file.

Comment: Also take a look at this article http://www.rafael-salas.com/2008/03/ssis-and-dynamic-excel-destinations_01.html